# how reset all contents of page without reloading page in GWT

Tags: gwt, tabs, refresh, reload, reset

I have tabpanel in my application. i just want to refresh all the contents of the tab whenever i navigate through different tabs. Currently i am using Window.Location.Reload for the same. But is there any other way out for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add a TabListener to the TabPanel using the method `addTabListener(TabListener listener)`. You will be notified when a tab is selected. You can put your logic of refresh in that method.